# How to build this navigation in liftweb(scala language)?

Tags: scala, lift

the code is:

```
val nav =  Menu(Loc("Home",List("index"),"home"))  :: 
Menu(Loc("Daily",List("daily"),"daily")) ::
Menu(Loc("Photo",List("photo"),"photo")) ::Nil`
```

I use scala and liftweb 
but I troubled when I built navigation in snippet

Comment: What kind of troubles do you have? It does not compile? Does not do what you want? Fails at runtime? ...